# Mouse not clicking the intended image using sikuli library for robot framework on virtual machine (azure)

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

i am currently running robot tests using sikuli library(for a desktop application) on a virtual machine in azure. 
I have problems with mouse not clicking  intended image. and i get the error below.

```
[error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(209,150)@S(0)[0,0 2049x1152]

but after move is `L(210,150)@S(0)[0,0 2049x1152]`

Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running:
Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application.
You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.
[log] CLICK on L(209,150)@S(0)[0,0 2049x1152] (562 msec)
```

Could someone help me how to solve this issue. i tried running the script as an admin and also checked resolution but still doesnt work. 
Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That message is thrown usually because lack of privileges. If you tried running the program vía command line, try to create a new user with Administrative privileges. Later, execute the program with Shift + Left Click --> Run as ... and enter the new credentials. That should work.